OpenAI pip error while installing (Rust manager issue?)
I just tried to intall openai on my pip venv, and I got this error.
My pip is up to date and I tried on 2 different environments.
My command that i entered was:
pip install openai
I wanted to install openai api using pip and got an unusual error back.
Error Message:
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      
      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
      
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Did you follow the advice it gave?

Your error message is quite descriptive and it provides a solution to your question: Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
openai package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. You can install it through the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/.

This error is from Pydroid on Android.  Unfortunately Rustup cannot be installed on Android as it's not supported.... boooo
Maybe I'll solve this and get an update.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
